# Copy specific lines from cmd using a batch file

Tags: html, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to create a batch file that copies information from specific lines in command line (who are also generated by the same batch file using commands) to a text file for use in an html file.

The specific pieces of information I need are computer name, ip address, and the current user who is logged in (I know how to get those) and i need them copied to either 1 text file, or 3 separate ones (which ever is easiest to move the string from there into a webpage, which is called from the same batch file.)

The purpose of this is to make it easier for employees to submit help desk tickets by way of a "panic button" that when executed will automatically collect information on the computer and submit it to our ticketing system.

Comment: I have no code mostly because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The question could be clearer but removing the incidental remarks and supplying the missing assumptions.  I believe your question boils down to this:

-> capture output of specific command line statements in a batch file to a text file.

You can use the redirect operators to accomplish this:

**echo** a bunch of text **>** a.txt
**dir** **>** b.txt

You can use any command that outputs text to the console and redirect it as shown.  Now, if you want to use a single file, use >> as shown:

**echo** a bunch of text **>** a.txt
**dir** **>>** a.txt

The double-arrow says to "append" rather than overwrite any existing file of that name, so a.txt has the output from both.

Comment: Thanks! but how would you output a specific line of the result of the command (such as the ip address)?